# Get user mail id by clicking a link in eMail

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am using a link button in a mail which will be sent to different persons (Consider same mail server). If a user clicks from his mail, he will be redirected to a particular Web API.

I need to know **"which mail user has clicked the link button?"** from the mail.

TIA.

Comment: you could add a token to the url which would identify which user clicked the link...

Comment: Any implementation idea / code pls?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add a link to the button in the email which passed a unique identifying token to the page that you could then track.

Some systems will have the link go through to a tracking link first that logs the link press and the redirects the user to the final destination. This is a common pattern used by systems like MailChimp.

Comment: The email will be  sent to multiple email id's containing multiple To and Cc's ,and the email contains web link. i want to know which person / from which email id web link has been clicked. Also, If I use a tracking Id, the id will be same since the same mail will be delivered to all recipients.

Comment: @sathya then force the users to log in to use the API.